# Does overall phase matter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

If it's experimentally known that a measurement of $S_x$, after measuring $S_z$, results in $\hbar/2$ half of the times, and $-\hbar/2$ the other half, is it correct to claim that
$$|z\pm\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\left( |x+\rangle \pm e^{i\delta_1}|x-\rangle\right), \tag{1}$$
without caring about the overall phase? If yes (which, by the way, Sakurai claims to be correct in his book), then it similarly follows that 
$$|z\pm\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\left( |y+\rangle \pm e^{i\delta_2}|y-\rangle\right). \tag{2}$$

What's not so fine is that solving for $|x+\rangle$ and $|y+\rangle$ gives us
$$|x+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\left( |z+\rangle + |z-\rangle\right) = |y+\rangle \tag{3}$$

which is obviously wrong. $|x+\rangle$ cannot be equal to $|y+\rangle$.

So where did things go wrong? Does it all lie in ignoring the overall phase?

Comment: I'm not able to give a totally in-depth satisfactory answer yet, but I think Eq. (2) is the problem. By stipulating Eq. (1) and Eq. (2) at the same time, we're ignoring *two* overall phases. Quantum states have a single global phase which is arbitrary, but as soon as you pick it, you have to respect it everywhere else, and I think Eq. (1) is choosing that phase.

Comment: You're title is misleading. This isn't an overall phase, this is a *relative* phase. Big difference. If you just multiply your entire state by an overall phase, that **really** doesn't matter.

Comment: Here's a simple proof to convince you https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/208243/qm-and-relative-phases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only ignore the overall phase of a ket when you evaluate a physical quantity related to it. You can't dump overall phases everywhere when you're doing math on the kets themselves.

For example, suppose we have two kets $|x \rangle$ and $|y \rangle$ and we define
$$|z \rangle = |x \rangle + |y \rangle.$$
By your logic, this equation remains true under any phase redefinition of $|x \rangle$ and $|y \rangle$, so we have
$$|z \rangle = e^{i\theta_1} |x \rangle + e^{i\theta_2} |y \rangle$$
This is only true if the two $|z \rangle$'s are the same, i.e. if $\theta_1 = \theta_2$, in which case $|z \rangle$ itself just picks up an overall phase. If this isn't true, then you've mistakenly thrown away a relative phase between the $|x \rangle$ and $|y \rangle$ components, which has physical consequences.

Another way of saying this is that 'global phase' is only a single degree of freedom. You can rotate away any *one* phase in a problem, but you can't do that to all of them.

Comment: Your response makes perfect sense. My understanding now is that if what I'm doing is defining the state kets $|y\pm\rangle$, at a point where they aren't defined yet, I can adjust their overall phase in the definition, and I can do the same for the kets $|x\pm\rangle$ subsequently (here I twice chose an overall phase, but that's fine). But my mistake was that I wrote two formulas of $|z\pm\rangle$ and adjusted the overall phase twice. Is that right?

Comment: @Mohammed Yup, that's right!

Answer (score 0):

In this case the measurement given (projection along z) just doesn't tell you what the phase **is**, it doesn't mean that the phase is inconsequential. I.e., this means that any state of the form

$$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\uparrow\rangle+exp\{i \phi\} |\downarrow\rangle)$$

Yields the given probabilities. The error is then in the equals sign in equation 2. Just because the measurement outcomes are the same doesn't mean the states are equal.

Incidentally this poses a general problem if you want to completely know your quantum state by doing measurements on it. This principle implies that you must necessarily take measurements in more than one basis in order to fully define your state. This is heavily explored and studied in the field of quantum state tomography.

Comment: Obviously, you didn't see the subscripts on $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$

Comment: No I saw it, I'm saying that the phase matters, so that your equation of a state with one to the state with another is wrong. I'm not sure what made you think that I didn't see it, other than that my phase doesn't have a subscript.